# Creating Excel Automation add-in with VC++

Tags: excel, visual-c++, automation, add-in

I am newbie to Excel addins and Visual Studio.  After some search, I came up with the following steps to create Excel automation addin: (I am using VS 2012)

1. create a C++ ATL project
2. add a STL Simple object
3. right-click on the object and add a method (with a IN and RETVAL parameters)
4. build the solution
5. register the dll with regsvr32

I am able to register the dll successfully.  But the add-in does not show up in the Automation Servers available list in Excel 2010 (installed on my machine on Windows 7).  Excel is 32 bit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong regsvr32.  Since I am building 32bit dll, I should be using regsvr32 from \Windows\SysWOW64.